# How to get HTML of each paragraph of a Word document with Office JS

Tags: wordpress, ms-word, office-js

I have MS Word documents where the table of contents, built using title 1 to title 4, is a hierarchy of more than 100 items.

I want to use Office JS to develop an add-in to import these documents in WordPress as a set of Pages with the same hierarchy as one of the tables of contents.

Each WP page would contain the HTML of all the paragraphs contained under each title level.

Looking at the Office JS samples, I have been able to log to the console the outline levels of all paragraphs in the document, but I am stuck with getting the HTML.

I think this is probably because I misunderstand `context.sync()`.

Here is my code:

```
$("#exportToCMS").click(() => tryCatch(exportToCMS));

function exportToCMS() {
  return Word.run(function (context) {
    // Create a proxy object for the paragraphs collection
    var paragraphs = context.document.body.paragraphs;
    // Queue a command to load the outline level property for all of the paragraphs
    paragraphs.load("outlineLevel");
    return context.sync().then(function () {
      // Queue a a set of commands to get the HTML of each paragraph.
      paragraphs.items.forEach((paragraph) => {
        // Queue a command to get the HTML of the paragraph.
        var ooxml = paragraph.getOoxml();
        return context.sync().then(function () {
          console.log(ooxml.value);
          console.log(paragraph.outlineLevel);
        });
      });
    });
  });
}

/** Default helper for invoking an action and handling errors. */
function tryCatch(callback) {
  Promise.resolve()
    .then(callback)
    .catch(function (error) {
      console.error(error);
    });
}
```

If I comment out the line which logs `ooxml.value`, the script runs fine.

When uncommented, I get an error "Unhandled promise rejection".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Broken promise chains are common when you have a `context.sync` inside a loop. This is also bad from a performance standpoint. Your first step to fixing your code is to get the `context.sync` out of the `forEach` loop by following the guidance in this article: [Avoid using the context.sync method in loops](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/concepts/correlated-objects-pattern).

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the right direction, it's working fine now.

Comment: @EricMalalel please mark the answer as accepted so that it counts as answered in Stack's statistics. Thanks.